# Why is my app crashing due to an overreleased NSPathStore2?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

My app crashes with this (after the end of viewDidLoad):

```
-[NSPathStore2 release]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

A similar issue was reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141361/my-application-crash-when-its-first-time-debugging-in-simulator-and-device-too-af), but I'm not using any explicit NSPathStore2 instances, so I don't know where this is coming from.  I know this is a memory-related issue, but I'm not sure how to track it down

What could be causing this overreleased NSPathStore2?  What is an NSPathStore2?

Comment: Have you enabled NSZombies?  If so, when you debug with breakpoints on, where does your application stop in the debugger?  What is the backtrace at that point?

Comment: This question seems to be a potential duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272484/what-is-a-nspathstore2-lets-figure-it-out question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSPathStore2` is an internal object used by `NSString` for path work. You're almost certainly overreleasing an `NSString` somewhere in your code. The static analyzer will probably show you where: assuming you're using Xcode 4, choose Analyze from the Product menu.

Comment: i didnt had xcode 4 at that moment :(, anyways it took a while but i finally learned to use self.variable xD!