# What is a NSPathStore2?

Tags: xcode, debugging, nsstring, allocation

All that I know is this:

- Its private
- Its created somehow cause of strings trying to do Path related things

I mean, if they are private and still my app is telling me that NSPathStore2 is interfering, I need to know **why**. I just want to understand why a release of NSPathStore2 is making my app crash.

Comment: Where's the code?  What are you doing to trigger the release of that private class object?

Comment: Paths are arguments to file methods.  Like NSFileHandle.  So where are you doing file operation?

Comment: I postulate that the question is useful, but is formed improperly.  The real question here is "What type of object is an NSPathStore2 object and how should I expect to be able to treat it.  With THAT as the question, the accepted answer becomes very relevant.

Comment: Just edited it to fit better. 7 upvotes show it's a valid question.

Comment: Probably you are making a mistake with your code that uses NSStrings (e.g. calling nonexistent function, etc) and seeing an exception mentioning NSPathStore2. NSPathStore2 is not causing the problem.

Comment: This should be reopened; I was concerned I wasn't getting strings in my array so I googled the type I saw, and this question is the first result, and the accepted answer completely addresses my concern

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`NSPathStore2` is a subclass of `NSString`, used when creating strings that contain paths. For all intents and purposes, you should treat it as a `NSString`.

Comment: Additionally, it's useful to know that `NSString` is referred to as a [class cluster (Apple docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html). `NSPathStore2` is one of many case-specific implementations of `NSString`

Comment: Well, sadly, that's not entirely correct. My testing found that NSPathStore2 performs normalization operations when comparing it against paths that a regular NSString object would not do. Even worse, it normalizes paths when using "hasPrefix" but not when using "isEqualToString", causing quite some ugly effects when you're not prepared for this.

Comment: I'm also finding it can cause a crash when using a category extension on NSString that doesn't exist on an NSPathStore2 “subclass”. Not sure the details, but it doesn't seem like it behaves exactly like an NSString.